# Python Code for Comparing two files and output the diff

Tags: python

I have code to compare two different files with certain lines in each file and print the diff. Suppose both the files have one line in common but in one of these files this line has a extra space at the very end.

## Example

File1:

1) line I want to compare

File2:

1) line I want to compare     (this has one extra space at the end of the line)

Current code thinks these lines are different because of the space at the end of the line in File 2, how can I modify the code so that it ignores the space at the end of the line and does not consider these lines as different.

### Current Code:

```
with open('file1.txt') as f:
    f1 = f.read().strip().splitlines()
f1a = set(f1)

with open('file2.txt') as f:
    f2 = f.read().strip().splitlines()
f2a = set(f2)

print "only in file1 and not in file2"
for diff in f1a-f2a:
    print f1.index(diff), diff

print "only in file2 and not in file1"
for diff in f2a-f1a:
    print f2.index(diff), diff
```

Comment: You need to `strip()` each string in `f1`. Use list comprehension.

Comment: Thanks a lot David , this worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently strip the read string, so you remove white-spaces before the first and after the last line, afterwards you split the string at the newlines. What you want is to strip every line.
Use something like

```
f1 = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
```

or

```
f1 = [line.strip() for line in f.splitlines()]
```

and the same for f2. I would also consider using `rstrip` instead of `strip` to remove only trailing white-spaces, as leading are often important as they mark indents and paragraphs.

Comment: No problem. If it fixed your problem, consider marking the answer that people know your problem is solved.